# Splash screen freezing on the bb7 simulator

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, blackberry, web-inspector

I am making a bb7 native applicatiion. I am compiling the code in command prompt using following code - 
`D:\BB7_Source\MyAppFolder>bbwp D:\BB7_Source\my_app.zip -g my_password -o D:\
BB7_Output.`

After compilation I am getting 2 folders - StandardInstall and OTAInstall. These 2 folder containing .cod and .jad files. I have loaded **StandardInstall->MyApp.cod** file to the simulator. Then simulator is freezing in splash screen. It is not taking me to the next screen. But, when I am using **OTAInstall->MyApp.jad** file in my bb7 mobile device, then it is woriking fine. But, in simulator I am not able to install .jad file. Its know only .cod file. Then how to run my native bb7 application in simulator. Please help to come out from this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I don't know anything about Web Works and the differences that might cause your screen to not load correctly.  The question I may be able to help with is:
"But, in simulator I am not able to install .jad file."

From the Browser in the Simulator, you may be able to load the jad file from the same web site that you can use for a standard device. You just need to have some communication working that the Browser supports.

On all Simulators, you should be able to start up the MDS Simulator and the Browser will use that.

On most later Simulators, you can enable a 'fake' WiFi and the Browser will use that.  To enable this fake WiFi, just go into Manage Connections, and choose the "Manage WiFi", and if you need to, ask it to scan for WiFi networks.  The Simulators have a simulated WiFi network defined, and the Browser should use that.

Hopefully this will get you the ability to load the application via the jad, and then you can see if it is the download method or the Simulator, which is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the simulator itself is freezing on *its* splash screen, then it's probably not a problem with your app.  Unless you have configured your app to run on startup, your app shouldn't be causing problems with the simulator before you choose to run the app (by selecting the home screen icon to launch it).

If you are using Eclipse, with the BlackBerry plugin, you can reset the simulator by using the **BlackBerry** menu, then choosing **Clean Simulator ...**.

Outside of Eclipse, you should still be able to navigate to the plugin folder for your simulator, and run `clean.bat`:

```
C:\eclipse\indigo\plugins\net.rim.ejde.componentpack5.0.0_5.0.0.36\components\simulator\clean.bat
```

Obviously, the *root* install path will be different for your computer.

This will reset the simulator to its default state, and often will fix any problems the simulator has starting cleanly.